# User control disappears instead of turning under RotateTransform

Tags: .net, wpf, rotatetransform

I'm having problems with `RotateTransform` behavior. 

I have a user control inside a `Grid` and it's rotated -135º, but when I move that shape to the limits of the `Grid`, it starts to disappear, acting like it has no rotation.  How can I fix this?

[alt text http://img522.imageshack.us/img522/6241/cenask.jpg](http://img522.imageshack.us/img522/6241/cenask.jpg)

Answer (score 1):

Judging by your description, I'd say the `UserControl` is being clipped by the boundary of the `Grid`, which is the expected default behavior. You can set the `ClipToBounds` property on your `Grid` to ensure any content that runs outside of it is not clipped.

For example, consider the following:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.Window1"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="Window1" Height="300" Width="300">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="50"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="50"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="50"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="50"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

        <Grid Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" ClipToBounds="True" Background="Blue">
            <Label Content="Testing a long label to see what happens" Background="Gray" RenderTransformOrigin=".5,.5">
                <Label.RenderTransform>
                    <RotateTransform Angle="-135"/>
                </Label.RenderTransform>
            </Label>
        </Grid>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

This results in:

[alt text http://img514.imageshack.us/img514/8485/screenshotmf.png](http://img514.imageshack.us/img514/8485/screenshotmf.png)

Changing `ClipToBounds` to `true` results in:

[alt text http://img36.imageshack.us/img36/2682/screenshottz.png](http://img36.imageshack.us/img36/2682/screenshottz.png)

Comment: Hello Kent.
Thanks for your reply. 
I have tested this solution but it doesn't work. 
Any more ideas?

Comment: dont your mean cliptobound=false in the second example?

Answer (score 0):

It might be an issue with where the rotation is being applied.

There is two properties on a RotateTransform (CenterX, CenterY) that determines the point at which to rotate around.

I quote from [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.rotatetransform.aspx)

> The CenterX and CenterY properties of the RotateTransform specify the point about which the object is rotated. This center point is expressed in the coordinate space of the element that is transformed. By default, the rotation is applied to (0,0), which is the upper-left corner of the object to transform.
>
> The next example rotates a Polyline object clockwise 45 degrees about the point (25,50).

It's possible that it's rotating around the top left of your object, and if thats the set to the top left of the underlying canvas, then it will rotate outside of your canvas space.

Hope this helps